# How to add or subtract binary numbers using vba?

Tags: vba, excel, binary, binary-data

I have a data of 5-bits of binary numbers (10110, 10111, 01011, etc..), which are the data information of transmitted bits in the fiber.
Now I happened to do is that I need to sum and subtract few binary numbers, and these are high in volume.
So as I already have these data in my excel sheet, I was thinking of implementing VBA code to add and subtract the binary numbers.
I couldn't find any function that sums 1+1=10, I'm just finding that 1+1=2. Also, to subtract, there's a method of 1's and 2's compliment.
If there's something which can be done by VBA, kindly help me out. I have tried my best to code, but it sums 1+1=2.
Thanks!

Comment: `=DEC2BIN(BIN2DEC(A2)-BIN2DEC(A1))`

Comment: `worksheetfunction.BIN2DEC("0011") + worksheetfunction.BIN2DEC("0011")` then use `DEC2BIN` to get the result back to binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With 5-bit binaries in **A1** and **A2**, in another cell enter:

```
=DEC2BIN(SUM(BIN2DEC(A1),BIN2DEC(A2)))
```

[image]

As you see, *VBA* is not required.  If you really need *VBA* then:

```
Public Function BinSum(s1 As String, s2 As String) As String
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        BinSum = .Dec2Bin(.Sum(.Bin2Dec(s1), .Bin2Dec(s2)))
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: worksheet functions have a size limit

Answer (score 2):

Using VBA

`worksheetfunction.DEC2BIN(worksheetfunction.BIN2DEC("0011") + worksheetfunction.BIN2DEC("0011"))`

Comment: worksheet functions have a size limit